# How do I make Google Cloud Functions accept POST requests larger than 10KB?

Tags: python, http, post, google-cloud-functions, http-status-code-413

I have created a small Python program accepting HTTP triggers and uploaded it to Google Cloud Functions.  It works fine when I make a POST request whose body is less than 10KB.

However, when I exceed this value, the function fails to work and sends error code 413 (request entity too large) in its response.  Is there something I might be missing?  When I read the quotas doc page, it says that Google Cloud Functions should allow requests of up to 10MB, which is clearly much more than what I am sending.

Thanks.

Edit:

The Python code parsing the POST data is as follows:

```py
def html_switcher_test(request):

    request_args = request.args

    if request_args:

        report_html = BeautifulSoup(request.args['data'], 'lxml')
```

A Postman request screenshot showing the error is provided below:

[image: Postman POST Error]

Comment: How confident are you that the request is actually 10K?  Stackoverflow seems to be littered with questions for folks who want to send > 10MB but so far no concerns about 10K.

Comment: Could you post the snipped of Python code that's causing the problem? Also, if you have access to a debugger, try and find the size of the `body` variable, as @Kolban said.

Comment: To make sure I gave the right size for the request, I used Postman.  I am simply sending an HTML file as the content of the message, which the function processes.  To do this with Postman, I copy the contents of the file (whose size is 17KB for example), and place it within a POST request.

Comment: I've added the Python code parser to the question (and a Postman screenshot).  Like I said, with lesser POST sizes (e.g. 7KB), everything works fine.

Comment: I've tested the function locally (with large file inputs), and everything works fine from the Python side.

Comment: What if you change your Python code to simply return a 200 and then test again sending in the 10K message.  Does it still fail?  My wonder/thinking here is that we are seeing the 413 response and assuming it is the Cloud Function framework that is sending that.

Comment: Just to rule out another possibility, the answer you expect in your request exceeds 10 MB?

Comment: @Kolban, I have just tried your suggestion where I deployed the following ultra-basic code: `# !/usr/bin/python3
def basic_test(request):
    return 'Successful Return'
`.  This also fails and sends out the 413 error when I send a POST request with a 17KB body.

Comment: @HarifVelarde, my function simply edits the HTML passed in at its input and outputs it out again.  The result can either be the same size as the input or smaller; never larger.

Comment: Would it be possible to see the complete message being sent?  Can we also validate WHERE the message is being sent?  I'm surprised in looking at the response that it is HTML as opposed to just a content free response code.  I'd also suggest we look at the headers in the original request.  Could there be some massive piece of data in there?

Comment: I've being trying a number of tests to see if there are any issues with what I'm sending. I've now tried to simply send over plain chunks of Lorem text. As before, once you hit the ~10KB mark, the error message starts being sent. I also tried changing my program to read the json field rather than params; when I try this with large inputs, the program actually worked, even with a 100KB message. I always send POST requests using either Postman or the Python requests library as follows: res = requests.post('us-central1-website.cloudfunctions.net/basic_test', params={'data': data}).

Comment: When sending data using the json parameter, there doesn't seem to be any issue.  Do you have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Is there a way you can share the code in order to test this scenario?

Comment: Would you like a full working example?

Comment: Yes, if it is possible, I want to try to replicate this scenario.

Comment: I've reproduced the issue by creating the hello world (in python) function defined [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/first-python).  Then, you need to send a post request as follows: `requests.post('api/hello_http',data={'data':data})`, where the data variable contains a text payload larger than 15KB.  This will issue the error message 'Error: could not handle the request'.  If you switch this command to `requests.post('api/hello_http', json={'data':data})`, everything works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/149753461) has been filed for this issue with an internal bug linked to it. Further feedback will be provided through there.